# OWIN self hosted web API doesn't receive connections from different network

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, owin, self-hosting

This is not a duplicated question, I searched all the similar questions and they are similar but not the same issue.

I have OWIN self-hosted ASP.NET Web API in a windows service, I can access the API endpoints from the same machine or another machine but on the same network.

The issue is that I cannot access these API endpoints from another PC that's on a different network

I tried routing the API to my local IP address using two different ways:

`WebApp.Start<APIStartup>(url: "http://*:9008/");`

and  `WebApp.Start<APIStartup>(url: "http://{myIP}:9008/");`

and in both cases, I can access the endpoints from any device on the same network but not from outside the network.

I also tried to use my public IP (by getting it from Google using my IP), but when I use it I get an exception when starting the windows service.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is *probably* not related to your API directly but instead is related to a networking or firewall issue.  There are a couple of things that you can do to troubleshoot the problem, but I have a  clarifying questions first.

When you say that it works from the same network but not an outside network, are you talking about a different network inside a company, or are you talking about a computer on the internet?  If you are referring to a different network inside a company, then it is just a matter of someone configuring the proper network rules to route the traffic accordingly.

If you are referring to an outside network as a computer on the internet, then you need to set up the proper NAT configuration to tell the router to direct traffic properly.  if you are talking about your personal computer, I most definitely would not recommend that you do that.

As for troubleshooting the problem, if you can `ping` your computer from the one on the other network, then things are set up properly and you probably do have an issue with the configuration of your API,but if you can’t, then you need to resolve those issues first.

You can also use a tool like Wireshark to see the traffic on your network.  That will tell you if the network traffic from the other computer is making it to yours.

Hope that helps.